# Cannot mine using 1080 Ti on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I keep getting this error:

```
[OPENCL]:Allocating/mapping single buffer failed with: clEnqueueWriteBuffer(-4). GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single chunk. Bailing.
[OPENCL]:clEnqueueWriteBuffer(-38)
```

I am using cuda 8.0.61, nvidia driver 375.66, and when I use ethminer --list-devices I get:

```
[OPENCL]:
Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
[0] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 11711807488
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 2927951872
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 1024
```

I have tried all of these solutions ( https://github.com/ethereum/libethereum/pull/203 ) but it still doesn't work.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your driver. The 1080 ti came out after that driver was made.
For step 4, enter 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-381'

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

Comment: Thanks, initially driver 381 didn't work for me, that's why I had 375. I used purge command and the installed 381, restart the computer and now everything works, thanks!